# What is the meaning of the # sign in this C++ macro?

Tags: c++, macros

What does the `#` mean in this C++ macro:

```
#define ASSERT(expr)   \
   {if (!(expr)){CM_ERROR_TRACE("assert  "<< #expr <<" failed"); assert(expr);} }
```

Comment: Look up the Stringizing Operator.

Comment: Find a preprocessor reference or read your C++ book.

Answer (score 7):

This is the "stringizing" operator.  In a macro, if `x` is a macro parameter, then `#x` evaluates to a quoted string literal representation of the text of `x`.  For example, the macro

```
#define STRINGIZE(x) #x
```

evaluated in this context

```
STRINGIZE(2 + 3 + 4)
```

expands out to

```
"2 + 3 + 4"
```

Here, the macro is

```
#define ASSERT(expr)   \
   {if (!(expr)){CM_ERROR_TRACE("assert  "<< #expr <<" failed"); assert(expr);} }
```

The use of `#expr` here means that if the expression does not evaluate to true, it will print out a string representation of the macro argument.  For example

```
ASSERT(myFunction())
```

would expand to

```
{if (!(myFunction())){CM_ERROR_TRACE("assert " << "myFunction()" << " failed"); assert(myFunction());} }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OMG, we both used the same name for the macro :-P

Answer (score 4):

When the macro is pre-processed  `#expr` will be replaced with `"expr"`.

Answer (score 3):

`#` is a preprocessor operator that creates a string from token.

```
#define STRINGIZE(macro) #macro
```

`STRINGIZE(Hello)` will be replaced by "Hello"